# Ionic 5 - ion-content doesn't have a visible overflow (cannot scroll)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am working on migrating an Ionic 3 / Angular 5 app to Ionic 5 / Angular 11 and I have a problem with the layout of the page: when I use `ion-header` and `ion-content`, the content of the page is not scrollable. Here is my code:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-item lines="none">
            <ion-label>
                <ion-title>My title</ion-title>
            </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <!-- A lot of content here -->
    <!-- This is not scrollable -->
</ion-content>
```

By comparing the new layout with what I have in Ionic 3, while in Ionic 3 the header and the content have an `absolute` position with a top padding/offset (all these injected by Ionic), in Ionic 5 the position of the content is `relative` without any top padding. I am not sure if this is the real problem or what am I doing wrong, maybe there is something else I need to set.
Is there a setting I can use for Ionic 5 so the problem disappears? Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: The code provided is missing the closing `</ion-header>`. Is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: Yes, it was an error, sorry. I updated the question.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to double-check :) Could you please fork **[this stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-starter-app)** and try to reproduce the issue there?